# NDB BlobProperty 'compressed' option, can be set afterwards?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Google App Engine's Datastore `ndb.BlobProperty` has an option [compressed=True](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#compressed) where it will compress the data using zlib when writing and reading from the datastore, saving storage space.

However I discovered this later, after some entities with such `ndb.BlobProperty` are stored.

Is it safe to add `compressed=True`? Will the existing entities be read correctly (which are not compressed)?

I tried some in the [Cloud Playground](https://cloud-playground.appspot.com/playground/) and it seems to work, but since I couldn't find it on the docs, I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it will be read correctly. But note that entity will not become compressed if you will not update this property.
So, after adding `compressed=True`, to compress all existing entities you should run a job to:

```
entity.compressed_value = entity.compressed_value
entity.put()
```

It will not work if you will just "re put" all of them.

Use `len(entity._to_pb().Encode())` to check the size so you can know if it is compressed or not.